# How to run HLint?

Tags: haskell, hlint

I'm only a few weeks in to programming with Haskell. I was told to use HLint to improve my code. The problem is I can't figure out how to run HLint against my .hs file. I read [the documentation](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm#installation) and I was able to install it using `cabal install hlint`. The next step is running HLint using `hlint myfile.hs`. I can't figure our where to type this line. Neither cmd nor ghci will let me run the command. What am I missing here?

I'm using windows.

**edit:**

I just removed Haskell and installed it again on my system. I think the problem is with my Haskell installation. Thats what I'm getting when I try to install HLint again:
[image]

The file **does** exsist in `C:\Users\PCPCPCCP\AppData\Roaming\cabal\setup-exe-cache`

**edit2:**

Seems like hlint wasn't installed correctly. Even after reinstalling the haskell platform I am not able to install hlint it on my system. I did work on my virtual machine however...

Comment: It seems like you have a problem with installing packages in general, rather than HLint in specific, so I suggest you start with the simplest executable, and get that working first. In particular, I suggest you install the [hello](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hello) package (which is incredibly simple) and see if that works.

Answer (score 7):

Just run it on top of the Haskell file:

```
hlint filename.hs
```

You have to run that from the terminal in Linux or the PowerShell/CMD.exe in Windows.

A sample demo from my PC:

```
$ hlint gem.hs
gem.hs:9:9: Warning: Use void
Found:
  print "if" >> return ()
Why not:
  void (print "if")

gem.hs:10:9: Warning: Use void
Found:
  print "else" >> return ()
Why not:
  void (print "else")

2 suggestions
```

Comment: I still don't get it. So I have a file called t.hs with my haskell program. I can open CMD and run that program with no problem. Now you want me to add the line `$ hlint t.hs` on top of my t.hs file and then run in from CMD like before? I'm getting **parse error on input '$' Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell**

Comment: @isADon: In the CMD window, type `hlint t.hs`. The dollar sign is just meant to represent the command prompt, you don't actually type it anywhere. Does it give an error if you try to do this?

Comment: yes I get **the command "hlint" is spelled incorrectly or could not be found** (translated from german)

Comment: @isADon I think `hlint` is not in your PATH. Find where the executable file is present and put that location under the PATH environmental variable. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) for more details.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my haskell installation. Please see my edit in my question.

Comment: @isADon If you are starting to learn, I would suggest you to stick with [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) or use [Stackage repo](http://www.stackage.org/) for cabal-install.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the folder of cabal that stores all installed binaries in your environment variable PATH, i.e.,

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin/"`

Answer (score 1):

I just run it like this

```
hlint src/
```

where "src/" is the directory defined in the hs-source-dirs: line in my .cabal file.